# Kotlin Room DB Export schemas

Tags: kotlin, android-room, database-migration, jsonschema, database-schema

```kotlin
class RoomSchemaArgProvider(
  @get:InputDirectory
  @get:PathSensitive(PathSensitivity.RELATIVE)
  val schemaDir: File
) : CommandLineArgumentProvider {

  override fun asArguments(): Iterable<String> {
    // Note: If you're using KSP, you should change the line below to return
    // listOf("room.schemaLocation=${schemaDir.path}")
    return listOf("-Aroom.schemaLocation=${schemaDir.path}")
  }
}
```

I need to Export old db schema in json. I wanted to use the above code if any one used this as per https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#export-schemas please help me with the same.

i tried to use as per this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#export-schemas

problem faced during testing migration. hence i need this solution.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find the schema file in the assets folder. Make sure to include the exported json schemas in your test assert inputs. See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#export-schema for details. Missing file: com.sboxnw.freeplay.data.database.SugarBoxDatabase/2.json
> at androidx.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper.loadSchema(MigrationTestHelper.java:484)
> at androidx.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper.createDatabase(MigrationTestHelper.java:238)
> at com.sboxnw.freeplay.DownloadMigrationTest.testAllMigrations(DownloadMigrationTest.kt:72)

I need to Export all old db json schema for migration testing .

Answer (score 0):

It is failing due to src path not define correctly. You can add source path directly in defaultConfig of build.gradle

```
javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
```